# Where is the Xcode build results file?

Tags: xcode, build

The Xcode "Build Results" tab shows the build log.

Does anyone know where the actual log file (path in filesystem) is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it might be the `build-state.dat` file that you'll find nested in your build products folder.  This file is cryptic plain text, which is probably heavily filtered for display in the build results window.